# How to change mat-select height (style)?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, frontend

Using ***::ng-deep*** it solve the problem, but it affect all mat-select in the same module, so how can I change mat-select style juste in a specific component?

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel{
    max-height: none!important;
}
```

Edit:

```
<div class="col-md-2 kt-margin-bottom-10-mobile">
                        <div class="kt-form__control">
                            <mat-form-field >
                                <mat-select [(value)]="searchOption"
                                            class="mat-form-field mat-form-field-fluid"
                                            placeholder="Search by...">
                                    <mat-option value="all"><span>All</span></mat-option>
                                    <mat-option value="ref"><span>Reference</span></mat-option>
                                    <mat-option value="name"><span>Name</span></mat-option>
                                    <mat-option value="team"><span>Team</span></mat-option>
                                </mat-select>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML too? If you are directly using the mat-select component, you can wrap it around a div / mat-form-field tag and give it a meaningful ID to it, and for that ID, add the above CSS. That should solve the issue

Comment: @SrikarPhaniKumarMarti I add the HTML to the Question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this then,

```
// Add an ID to the div in the HTML
<div class="col-md-2 kt-margin-bottom-10-mobile">
     <div class="kt-form__control">
         <mat-form-field id="search-option-id"> <-- Add the ID Here
              <mat-select 
                  [(value)]="searchOption"
                  class="mat-form-field mat-form-field-fluid"
                  placeholder="Search by..."
              >
                   <mat-option value="all"><span>All</span></mat-option>
                   <mat-option value="ref"><span>Reference</span></mat-option>
                   <mat-option value="name"><span>Name</span></mat-option>
                   <mat-option value="team"><span>Team</span></mat-option>
              </mat-select>
         </mat-form-field>
     </div>
 </div>



// In your CSS file, you can do this: 

#search-option-id > mat-select { <-- You can do this in the CSS
  ::ng-deep .mat-select-panel {
    max-height: none!important;
   }
}
```

Comment: that actually doesn't work, because the `.mat-select-panel` is not a child of our component. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the mat-select-panel is outside your component, in the `.cdk-overlay-container`. So you can't change CSS only for your own component's mat-selects.

What you CAN do, is adding a class to the select-panel, and then make a true ng-deep rule

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(value)]="searchOption"
                class="mat-form-field mat-form-field-fluid"
                panelClass="auto-height"                    <-- adding class to panel here
                placeholder="Search by...">
        <mat-option value="all"><span>All</span></mat-option>
        <mat-option value="ref"><span>Reference</span></mat-option>
        <mat-option value="name"><span>Name</span></mat-option>
        <mat-option value="team"><span>Team</span></mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and in your scss file:

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel.auto-height {
  max-height: none;
}
```

Or even better, add it to your material-overload.scss file if you already have one. If not, add it to your styles.scss file, so you don't use ng-deep at all:

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
  .mat-select-panel.auto-height {
    max-height: none;
  }
}
```